# Can anyone identify the S notification icon

Tags: notification-icons

Someone please help me identify the S at the top left corner of my picture

[image]

Comment: Please  swipe down to list notifications and tap on notification to open it. check  settings, whether you have installed any launcher or app named with S.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out finally. It is [Shopkick](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shopkick.app) app.